# How do I implement a bitset of k bits in C?

Tags: c, arrays, bitset

I have never worked with bit operations in C, but now I need to, because I need my program to be CPU efficient.

I have a big array `int *v`which contains `k`, numbers (`k` is known) and my program will set each `v[i]` to zero, in an undefined order, and will store the index `i` in an array `int *q`. Before storing the index I have to check if the index is already in `q`, so I won't store it twice. This check takes up a lot of time. I was thinking of implementing a bitset `k` bits, each set to zero and when I add index `i` to `q`, I would also set the bit `i` from my bitset to one. Before that I need to check if the `i` bit is not already one. How can I do that?

I did check if other questions already have my answer, but I didn't understand very well since I'm new to programming.

Comment: `"I have never worked with bit operations in C, but now I need to, because I need my program to be CPU efficient."` Well then you should start by not using bit operations. They're slow and CPU-inefficient. The only reason you'd use a bitset instead of an array of bytes is to save memory. You'd have to require **a lot** of bits to make this worth your while.

Comment: Addressing individual bits does not usually help performance.  Perhaps you can explain at a higher level what you're trying to accomplish, not in terms of bits?

Comment: "Before storing the index I have to check if the index is already in q, so I won't store it twice" – looks like the data structure you're looking for is a set.

Comment: To be CPU efficient, you could just use an array of `int* v`, where each position has boolean semantics to indicate whether `i` is contained in the set, i.e. `v[i]` is `1` if `i` is contained in the set and `0` otherwise (or the other way round, whatever is more suitable). I would guess this to perform much better than indexing out individual bits.

Comment: What's the maximum value for `k` ?

Comment: After I left to school today I realised that my question was pretty stupid. What I wanted was to declare a char *a; a=malloc(k,sizeof(char));. This is my "bitset" and my algorithm is much faster now. Thank you for your answers.